# Selected TreeViewItem is null

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, contextmenu, selecteditem

I wanted to create a ContextMenu for my TreeView. TreeView XAML:

```
<helper:ExtendedTreeView Grid.Row="5" ItemsSource="{Binding OCFrage, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem_="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItemChanged="treeView1_SelectedItemChanged" x:Name="treeView1" Height="205" Width="215">
    <helper:ExtendedTreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:T_Frage}" ItemsSource="{Binding Wertung, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </helper:ExtendedTreeView.Resources>
</helper:ExtendedTreeView>
```

while helper:ExtendedTreeView is this class:

```
public class ExtendedTreeView : TreeView
{
    public ExtendedTreeView()
        : base()
    {
        this.SelectedItemChanged += new RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<object>(self);
    }

    void self(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        if (SelectedItem != null)
        {
            SetValue(SelectedItem_Property, SelectedItem);
        }
    }

    public object SelectedItem_
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(SelectedItem_Property); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItem_Property, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItem_Property = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem_", typeof(object), typeof(ExtendedTreeView), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

I'm using this for binding the SelectedItem and use it in my ViewModel.

My TreeView has "Headers" which are of type T_Frage and their nodes are of type T_Wertung, so it would be

- T_Frage

  - T_Wertung
  - T_Wertung
- T_Frage

  - T_Wertung
    ...

I wanted to create a ContextMenu for the Headers. So if the user clicks on the TreeViewItem of type T_Frage, a ContextMenu should popup. I've followed this guide http://canhandre.wordpress.com/2012/01/14/wpf-treeview-with-contextmenu/ and I'm doing it currently in the CodeBehind just to test it. The problem is that when this code is being executed: `TreeViewItem selectedItem = treeView1.SelectedItem as TreeViewItem;` treeView1.SelectedItem is of type T_Frage and has it's values, but when I assign to selectedItem, selectedItem is still null... Why?

Edit: Removing the ItemsSource and creating normal TreeViewItems in XAML

```
  <TreeViewItem Header="Edit" Name="Edit">
       <TreeViewItem Header="Text"/>
       <TreeViewItem Header="Image"/>
       <TreeViewItem Header="Table"/>
  </TreeViewItem>
```

will assign the value here `TreeViewItem selectedItem = treeView1.SelectedItem as TreeViewItem;`. This means I can't assign a Item in my TreeView, which is of type T_Frage, to a variable of type TreeViewItem. How am I supposed to create a ContextMenu for a Item in my TreeView which is not of type TreeViewItem? Like you can see above, assigning the type of T_Frage to TreeViewItem will result as null.

Comment: So, before you execute the assignment step, `treeView1.SelectedItem` is an object, but `selectedItem` is `null` after the assignment, correct? What about `treeView1.SelectedItem`  after the assigment, is it still an object?

Comment: @Treb yes it is. `treeView1.SelectedItem` stays the same and `treeView1` is of type Helper.ExtendedTreeView. If I try to do it like this: `TreeViewItem selectedItem = (TreeViewItem)treeView1.SelectedItem;` it says InvalidCastException, because treeView1.SelectedItem is of type T_Frage. I just want to create a ContextMenu for this Item when it's being right clicked, but I can't create a ContextMenu for an item which is not of type TreeViewItem (as far as I know..). I've also tried `Helper.ExtendedTreeView selectedItem = treeView1.SelectedItem as Helper.ExtendedTreeView;
`, still null.

Comment: Well, I get the treeView1.SelectedItem as type of object. I've already tried it with your method and then assign the object to TreeViewItem, but it's still null or when I try to cast the object to type TreeViewItem, it's again InvalidCastException. so doing `object selectedItem = (object)treeView1.SelectedItem` and then `TreeViewItem twv = (TreeViewItem)selectedItem;` won't work.

Comment: No surprise, if the cast to a `TreeViewItem` didn't work on `treeView1.SelectedItem`, it won't work on `selectedItem` either. Can you provide some more code, about what you want to do with the `selectedItem` - how do you use it to create the context menu?

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's MVVM now and not CodeBehind, but I just wanted to test it in CodeBehind first and then do it all in MVVM, because I thought doing it right away in MVVM would be harder... Anyway, this is what I wanted:

```
<helper:ExtendedTreeView Grid.Row="5" ItemsSource="{Binding OCFrage, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem_="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItemChanged="treeView1_SelectedItemChanged" x:Name="treeView1" Height="205" Width="215">
    <TreeView.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding OCContext}"/>
    </TreeView.ContextMenu)
    <helper:ExtendedTreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:T_Frage}" ItemsSource="{Binding Wertung, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </helper:ExtendedTreeView.Resources>
</helper:ExtendedTreeView>
```

ViewModel:

```
private object _selecteditem;
public object SelectedItem
{
    get { return _selecteditem; }
    set
    {
        OCContext = new ObservableCollection<T_Wertung>();
        if (value is T_Frage)
        {
            T_Frage selected = (T_Frage)value;
    //do something with selected
    OCContext.Add(new T_Wertung(1,"Test",100));
            }
        }
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedItem);
    }
}

private ObservableCollection<T_Wertung> _occontext;
public ObservableCollection<T_Wertung> OCContext
{
    get
    {
        if (_occontext == null)
            _occontext = new ObservableCollection<T_Wertung>();
        return _occontext;
    }
    set
    {
        _occontext = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => OCContext);
    }
}
```

Since I'm binding to the SelectedItem of the TreeView, I can ask if the SelectedItem is of type T_Frage. If it's true, I'll create a new variable of type T_Frage and set it's context to the value of the SelectedItem. Now I can do something with this item and then add an item to the List of the ContextMenu named `OCContext`. When I right click the item, the ContextMenu is being popped up and it shows the items of `OCContext`.

Comment: My XAML knowledge is close to zero, but this looks overly complicated to me. I'm sorry, but my only advice is to go back to the bare bone example you linked in your question. Implement it exactly like that (e.g. without deriving your own class from `TreeView`), make it as simple as possible. Once you get that to work you can extend it.