# Bind Header of WPF ContextMenu

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, treeview, contextmenu

I had a problem with TreeView-Binding and ContextMenu here: [Selected TreeViewItem is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587852/selected-treeviewitem-is-null/17590372#17590372)

Now I'm having this problem: I have the ContextMenu

```
<TreeView.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu x:Name="MyContext" ItemsSource="{Binding OCContext}" DisplayMemberPath="Text"/>
</TreeView.ContextMenu>
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gA1l.png]

(The image shows how my ContextMenu looks like, don't mind about the tabItem...).

As you can see, it's just the ContetMenu, no MenuItem! If the user clicks on Close, I want to do something in my ViewModel (raise a Command?). I'd also like to know which button/Menu he clicked. The amount of Menus is dynamically, since it's ItemsSource is being binded.

This is my ViewModel:

```
private ObservableCollection<T_Antwort> _occontext;
public ObservableCollection<T_Antwort> OCContext
{
    get
    {
        if (_occontext == null)
            _occontext = new ObservableCollection<T_Antwort>();
        return _occontext;
    }
    set
    {
        _occontext = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => OCContext);
    }
}
```

So all I want to do is to bind the ContextMenu (The "items" Close and CloseOtherThankThis) to my ViewModel, so when the user clicks on one of them, I want to access them in my ViewModel. This means I don't want to bind them one by one, I want somehow to get an event (ContextMenuItemClicked (?)) being called and use this in my ViewModel.

Btw. using MenuItem under ContextMenu will create another "Menu folder", so it would be

" " -> Close

" " -> CloseOtherThankThis

And I don't want it to look like this.

Edit: I'm currently getting the item like this:

```
    private void MyContext_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.MenuBase s = sender as System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.MenuBase;
        ItemCollection ic = s.Items;
        T_Antwort SelectedItem = (T_Antwort)ic.CurrentItem;
    }
```

Is there any possibility to get the selected item with binding?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you have tried it, but there's a PlacementTarget for context menu, which gives you the object that contains the context menu.

In one project I had, I made something like this:

```
 <MenuItem ...    Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}},Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItem
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know where I should use it. I've tried it with MenuItem and a CommandBinding with the above as CommandParameter, but the Command is not being execute?.. `Command="{Binding asd}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}},Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItem}"` , VM `asd = new RelayCommand<object>(asdexecute);`. It's also a second node, so MenuItem doesn't really fit in.

Comment: I don't know about mvvm...sorry...I was talking in traditional wpf. If you want an example I can give you a full example in traditional wpf.